# SQLiteExceptiopn was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, sqlite, data-binding, datatable, exception

I'm trying to update/insert new record from grid to SQLite Database.

Here is how I bind grid:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bS = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource();
public SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter();

        public BindingSource GetData(string query)
        {
            try
            {
                dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, this.connectionString);
                SQLiteCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter.Fill(table);
                bS.DataSource = table;
            } catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

            return bS;
        }
```

And this is how I attach binding source to grid:

```
gridSirovina.DataSource = GetData.GetData(query);
```

When I try to save new record I'm doing it on this way:

```
try
{
    bnd.dataAdapter.Update((DataTable)bnd.bS.DataSource);
}
catch (SQLiteException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

If one of records that I'm trying to insert into database have same ID as already entered the application breaks and I get error:

> > An exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: constraint failed
>
> UNIQUE constraint failed: myTable.ID

**UPDATE**
Here is exception detail:

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147467259   Message=constraint failed UNIQUE constraint
>   failed: tblRoba.SifraRobe   Source=System.Data.SQLite   ErrorCode=19
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Reset(SQLiteStatement stmt)
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>          at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateRowExecute(RowUpdatedEventArgs
>   rowUpdatedEvent, IDbCommand dataCommand, StatementType cmdIndex)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)   InnerException:

I'm wondering why I can't intercept this error inside try...catch block?

Comment: So you are saying that `MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());` is not hit when you try to add a new record with the same ID

Comment: Exactly that. I'm little confused because I think that code is correct but I don't understand why breaks.

Comment: Have you tried `catch (Exception ex)` to see if  it catches

Comment: I had tried. This was the first thing I tried and I thought that this might be cause of problem and than I replace with SQLiteException.

Comment: Would be cool if you could provide a stack

Comment: The strange this is messasge: was not handled in user code. Update is inside try...catch and that confuses me.